# Workspace variable not printing in Jenkins Pipeline post step

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

i have configured a Jenkins pipeline job as follows
and env.WORKSPACE works fine

```
steps {
script
{
echo "${env.WORKSPACE}"
}
}
```

during build ouput is /home/mach1/workspace

but when i added some lines in post build stage in jenkins pipeline job.
it is returning the following `error ${FILE,path="echo "${env.WORKSPACE}"/dir1/file2.html"}`

```
script
{
echo "${env.WORKSPACE}"
}
}
 post{
  success{
   script{ 
body:'${FILE,path="${env.WORKSPACE}/dir1/file2.html"}'
}
}
}
```

may i know where its getting wrong, or how do i correct so that in post step it takes /home/mach1/workspace/dir1/file2.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A shell environment variable is referenced as a key within the `env` Map within Jenkins Pipeline Groovy, and as a string within the shell step method. In your original example, you referenced the variable as a Groovy variable, and interpolated it within the pipeline with the correct `"` syntax. However, in your second example, you are still referencing the variable as a Groovy variable, but attempting to interpolate it within the executed shell command from the step method. This will not work, as you will pass a literal string of the `env` Map variable.

You can fix this either by referencing the environment variable as a shell environment variable by removing the `env` Map key:

```
body:'${FILE,path="${WORKSPACE}/dir1/file2.html"}'
```

or by interpolating the Groovy variable within the pipeline:

```
body:"\${FILE,path=\"${env.WORKSPACE}/dir1/file2.html\"}"
```

where characters are properly escaped to denote a shell variable `FILE` as opposed to a Groovy variable, and for the embedded `"`.

The first correction is, of course, easier to read, and probably what you will prefer.

Comment: i tried this already **body:'${FILE,path="${WORKSPACE}/dir1/file2.html"}'**   but this one not working

Comment: this works **body:"\${FILE,path=\"${env.WORKSPACE}/dir1/file2.html\"}"**

Comment: Please mark this answer as accepted if it is correct and worked for you